# Errno 13 Permission Denied - when trying to read csv file with vs code on windows machine

Tags: python, csv, permission-denied

I am trying to access a csv file with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Define the path to the CSV file
file_path = "./InputFileValidation/Dummy2023raw.csv"

# Read the CSV file
try:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

    # Extract and print the headers
    headers = df.columns.tolist()
    print("Headers in the CSV file:")
    print(headers)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

The folder structure is as follows: parent / NetWork_Optimization / InputFileValidation / Dummy2023raw.csv
The python file can be found here: parent / NetWork_Optimization / test.py

I am running VS Code as administrator, it has all the required permissions to read/write, the file is closed..

When running the code I still get the below error:

```
An error occurred: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './InputFileValidation/Dummy2023raw.csv'
```

Does anyone have a clue of what is going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the file itself does not have any write/read restrictions?

Comment: If you have the file open in Excel, it is blocked. Close Excel and try again. If you don't have it open, try ending all python.exe instances.